# Too many vertices are created in a building

Tags: vertices

I tried to follow a youtube video and created a building and when I created, it seems the vertices are somewhere around 7000, then finally it becomes to some millions. I m not sure how it got into those many numbers. Please can someone help me finding it? I selected that building in edit mode, it comes to 5700. But the overall statistics showing some millions. is it because of texturing? Please help me to understand it. Below is the picture that I am creating... [image]

Comment: For repeating blocks, model a single one and use instances (via the Array Modifier)

Comment: try to simplify your original object as much as possible and use Array as proposed by Susu or linked-duplications (Alt D instead of Shift D)